# How do I Make force:recordEdit Component Styled Like recordView?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I am trying to use the :

```
<force:recordEdit/>
```

Component to show records in Salesforce1. When I use:

```
<force:recordView/>
```

It is styled nicely and looks good. recordEdit, however, looks completely un-styled. Why is this? Is there an easy way to add style to the component to replicate the view component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this.

If you use force:recordEdit within Lightning Experience, it will be styled correctly. Otherwise, the styling cannot be implemented in a robust and consistent way. I have spent a long time interrogating the classes required (and their sources), but there seems to be no way to handle the various gotchas that arise (dealing with date widgets, handling styling responsively based on changing view size, etc.)

I've created an idea regarding this in the hope of getting it resolved:

[Lightning Component force:RecordEdit - Apply correct styling automatically](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3tTQAS)